# Instantiating a new function no access to inner function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This is quite a frustrating issue I am stuck on. I am exporting a parent function with quite a rigid structure for the purpose of library mocking.

```
const responses = require("../responses/index.js");
function fetch (
    first = "contactsMultiple",
    second = "passwordFail",
    third = "contactsMultiple") {

this.first = first;
this.second = second;
this.third = third;
this.iteration = 1;

this.fetch = () => {
    let body;
    switch (this.iteration) {
        case 1 :
            body = responses.contacts[this.first];
            break;
        case 2 :
            body = responses.password[this.second];
            break;
        case 3 :
            body = responses.contacts[this.third];
            break;
        default:
            body = responses.contacts["contactsMultiple"];
            break;
    }

    const response = {
        status: 200,
        statusText: "OK",
        json: () => {
            return body;
        }
    };

    this.iteration++;
    return response;
}}
module.exports = fetch;
```

I export this, then import it, create a new instance of the function so I can set properties that I wish to increment and also set via the construction of the function. But the code then expects a function called fetch.

I need to be able to call it like:

```
const Fetch = new fetch();
```

then pass `Fetch` into the existing classes.

If I log this new function I can see it has a fetch property of a type function. but I keep getting `this.fetch is not a function`.

What am I missing?

Many thanks

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: With this piece of code is impossible to help you.

Comment: That code has a variable `responses` that will be used in your switch `body = responses.contacts[this.first];` there is a problem there, post a complete and verifiable example.

Comment: I have added the few missing bits, there isn't much left out only imported json and its export code.

Comment: Testing your code with a sample of `responses`, everything is working as expected.

Comment: We need more context from your scenario. Look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/ebzscvr4/